# Cannot loop through syllables and fetch it back into my CMS

Tags: javascript, jquery

I cannot seem to loop through my `syllables`, while I do the exact same thing with my `word`. This however does work, how come?

my JSON:

```
{
"main_object": {
"id": "new",
"getExerciseTitle": "Example",
"language": "nl_NL",
"application": "lettergrepen",
"main_object": {
  "title": "Example",
  "language": "nl_NL",
  "exercises": [
    {
      "word": "espresso",
      "syllables": [
        "es",
        "presso",
        "",
        ""
      ]
    }
  ]
},
"dataType": "json"
 }
}
```

my loop for the `syllables`:

```
  var exerSyll = json.main_object.main_object.exercises;

$.map(exerSyll, function(exerSyll, s) {
  $(".syllable" + s).val(exercise.syllables)
});
```

the loop I have for my `word` that does work:

```
var exercise = json.main_object.main_object.exercises;

$.map(exercise, function(exercise, i) {
 $("#addOpdracht").click();
 $(".exerciseGetWordInput_" + i).val(exercise.word) 

});
```

where it should append the `syllables`:

```
 function getWordPartInput(id, cValue){
  cValue = cValue || '';
  var wpInput = $('<input/>', {
 'class': 'form-group form-control syllable',
 'type': 'text',
 'value': cValue,
 'placeholder': 'Syllables',
'name': 'Syllablescounter['+ SyllablesID++ +']'
 });
  return wpInput;
}
```

Comment: `exercise.syllables` is an array, You need to iterate it

Comment: Could you elaborate on that please?

Comment: `$.each(exerSyll, function (exerSyll, s) {
 $.each(exerSyll.syllables, function (syllable, index) {
  $(".syllable" + index).val(syllable)
 });
});
`